# Dispose (free) a whole binary search tree

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I am trying to create my iterative approach of disposing a whole BST.

And I am not getting the expected output after I insert the nodes via my function insert_nodes.

It should print something like: left,right, #nr #nr #nr for numbers 5,3,4

I know that it is quite easy to do it recursively but I want to do it iterative. I am quite confused with pointers and free's, because I have to free all nodes.

I appreciate any type of help and explanations.

```
struct node
{
  int value;
  node *left;
  node *right;
}node;

void disposeBST(*node root)

if (root == NULL)
    return;

  node *ptr = root;

  while (ptr != NULL )
  {
     if(ptr->right != NULL){
      printf("left");
      ptr= ptr->left;

    }
  if(ptr->right != NULL)
    {
      printf("right");
      ptr =ptr->right ;

    }
  }
  printf("#nr");
  free(root);
  ptr = 0;
  }
```

Comment: You'll *need* a stack for the nodes, since your nodes do not have links to parents.

Comment: Hence your iterative approach will be more difficult to program than the recursive one.

Comment: Dispose meaning freeing I guess? This function is only freeing the `root`. Also where is the iteration?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have edited the code so it looks now as it should be

Comment: Still a single `free` call. Without going too much into the other logic..

Comment: It seems odd to test `ptr->right != NULL` and then process `ptr->left` and print `left`.  However, that's probably a typo-glitch.  Get a version of the function working recursively.  Only then work out how to use the general rules for converting recursive code to iterative code (a stack is needed).  You probably need a post-order traversal of your tree — or, at least, you need to accumulate the child nodes as outstanding work before freeing the current node.

Comment: I believe the BFS approach could work as well. If you prefer a queue over stack.

Answer (score 0):

Basic way to do this:

```
disposeBST(node *root) {
    struct stack stack;
    stack_init(&stack);
    if (root) stack_push(&stack, root);
    while (!stack_empty(&stack)) {
        node *ptr = stack_pop(&stack);
        if (ptr->left) stack_push(&stack, ptr->left);
        if (ptr->right) stack_push(&stack, ptr->right);
        free(ptr);
    }
    stack_destroy(&stack);
}
```

implementation of `struct stack` and the associated `stack_` functions left as an excercise for the reader...